# R: How to offset and match within a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, match, offset

I would like to use something similar to the OFFSET and MATCH functions of Excel, here is an example data set:
data=

```
Which Test?|Test1   |Test2  |Test3  |RESULT
Test1      |TRUE    |80%    |0      |
Test2      |FALSE   |25%    |0      |
Test1      |TRUE    |16%    |0      |
Test3      |FALSE   |12%    |1      |
```

Result column should read:

```
Which Test?|Test1   |Test2  |Test3  |RESULT
Test1      |TRUE    |80%    |0      |TRUE
Test2      |FALSE   |25%    |0      |25%
Test1      |TRUE    |16%    |0      |TRUE
Test3      |FALSE   |12%    |1      |1
```

In the final RESULT column I would like the test result of searching the Which test? column. In this example the RESULT column could return, for example, numbers or strings. In the Excel formula would be:

```
=OFFSET($A$1, ROW()-1,MATCH(A2,$B$1:$D$1,0))
```

I have tried to list the Tests using sapply so far and return this to another function such as which(colnames... and this is where I am stuck.

Comment: What have you already tried yourself?

Comment: May be `library(data.table); setDT(data)[, Result := if(any(.SD == "TRUE")) "TRUE" else NA, .SDcols = c("Test1","Test2","Test3")]` Need more explanation.

Comment: Thanks Veerendra but from my understanding your code searches for TRUE in the Test columns and returns TRUE if it finds it otherwise NA. The result I want returned could actually be a number (or string, etc). I have updated the question above and have added the search I am trying.

Comment: @BhavShah the question does not show an update yet

Comment: Sorry just updated now

Comment: @BhavShah could you explain on what conditions you are filling the values in result column?

Comment: Looking at your desired output, you probably need something like this: `data$RESULT <- ifelse(data$Test1==TRUE, TRUE, ifelse(data$Test3==1, 1, data$Test2))`

Comment: @Jaap I assume Test1 is not necessary TRUE as test3 is not necessary 1, if you shuffle the first column, the ifelse will or will not work

Comment: @Tensibai this what I deduced from OP's question, but it could certainly be true that another logic is needed (that's why I used the phrase "something like"); some clarification from the OP on the needed logic would nice

Comment: @VeerendraGadekar OK so I am looking down the 'Which test' column and trying to use this to search the columns to extract the result into the final Result column. There are a number of tests I am running on my data which produce a variety of outputs e.g. mean, max, pass/fail, percentages etc.

Comment: @Jaap See my answer for the logic I understood :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll go with sapply:

```
data <- read.table(text="Which Test?|Test1   |Test2  |Test3  |RESULT
Test1      |TRUE    |80%    |0      |
Test2      |FALSE   |25%    |0      |
Test1      |TRUE    |16%    |0      |
Test3      |FALSE   |12%    |1      |", 
 header=T, 
 sep="|",
 stringsAsFactors=F,
 strip.white=T)

data$RESULT <- sapply( 1:nrow(data), function(x) { data[x,data[x,1]] })
```

For each row, get the target column `data[x,1]` (the inner access), and for this column get the row value `data[x,...]`.

Output:

```
> data
  Which.Test. Test1 Test2 Test3 RESULT Result
1       Test1  TRUE   80%     0     NA   TRUE
2       Test2 FALSE   25%     0     NA    25%
3       Test1  TRUE   16%     0     NA   TRUE
4       Test3 FALSE   12%     1     NA      1
```

With two vars the function in the `sapply` would be:

```
function(x) {
 tcol <- data[x,1] # First column value of row x
 data[x,tcol]) # Get the value at row x and column tcol
}
```

An approach using `Map/mapply` would be to provide the 'i' (`seq(nrow(data))`), 'j' (`match(data$Which.Test., names(data))`) row/column index and use `[` to extract the elements from the 'data'.  We wrap with `list` so that the 'data' remains as a single data.frame and will recycle through the lengths of  'i', 'j'.

```
 mapply(`[`, list(data), seq(nrow(data)), match(data$Which.Test., names(data) ) )
 #[1] "TRUE" "25%"  "TRUE" "1"
```

---

Though, a possible vectorized approach would be just

```
data[cbind(1:nrow(data), match(data$Which.Test., names(data)))]
## [1] " TRUE" "25%"   " TRUE" "1"
```

This is matching the values in `Which.Test.` against the column names of `data` and returning the index of the matched column. Then, we subset these columns per each row by combining it with `1:nrow(data)` using `cbind`.

More detailed explanation of @DavidArenburg solution above (as I had to spend some time to understand it fully):

The subset operator accepts a matrix so we do:

1. `1:nrow(data)` easy it gives a vector `[1] 1 2 3 4` corresponding to the number of rows in our dataset
2. `match(data$Which.Test., names(data)))` giving the index of each matching test `[1] 1 2 3 4`
3. `cbind(..,..)`bind our two preceding point to build a matrix:

   ```
        [,1] [,2]
   [1,]    1    2
   [2,]    2    3
   [3,]    3    2
   [4,]    4    4
   ```

   We see this matrix match for each row the column we wish to take the value of. So when giving this matrix as the selector of our dataset we get the correct results. Then we can assign it to a new variable or to a new column of the df.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your answer and helping with how to read in data as well (sorry first post)!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(tidyr)
out = subset(gather(data, key, RESULT, 2:4), Which_Test == key)
req = unique(merge(data, out[,-2], by = "Which_Test"))

#>req
#  Which_Test Test1 Test2 Test3 RESULT
#1      Test1  TRUE   80%     0   TRUE
#3      Test1  TRUE   16%     0   TRUE
#5      Test2 FALSE   25%     0    25%
#6      Test3 FALSE   12%     1      1
```

Here using `Which_test` as constant, `Test` columns are gathered together into a single column called `RESULT` *(using `gather` from `tidyr` package)* simultaneously the names of `Test` columns are listed under `key` which is then used to filter the data based on the match against `Which_test` using base R's `subset`

**data**

```
data = structure(list(Which_Test = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 3L), 
      .Label = c("Test1","Test2", "Test3"), class = "factor"), 
       Test1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
       Test2 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
      .Label = c("12%", "16%", "25%", "80%"), class = "factor"), 
       Test3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), 
      .Names = c("Which_Test", "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Yes this works! I can always merge the output with the data if I need to but  this is very useful. Thanks for your answer and helping with how to read in data as well!